# Artist Mode Evil Integration

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying to be able to draw ascii art in emacs `picture-mode` by moving left, down, up, and right with the `j,h,k,l` keys in `evil-normal-mode`.

To do this I used these bindings:

`(nmap :keymaps 'picture-mode-map
      "k" (lambda ()
            (picture-movement-up)
            (picture-self-insert (string-to-char ".")))
      "j" (lambda ()
            (picture-movement-down)
            (picture-self-insert (string-to-char ".")))
      "h" (lambda ()
            (picture-movement-left)
            (picture-self-insert (string-to-char ".")))
      "l" (lambda ()
            (picture-movement-right)
            (picture-self-insert (string-to-char "."))))`

What I expect is a single insertion of the `.` and for the motion to be changed with the corresponding `picture-movement` function.

However when I tried out these bindings the direction of text being inserted was right but 46 characters were inserted at once. And the character was they key I pressed, not the period.

For example when I pressed `l` I'd get `llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll` immediately instead of just a gradual succession of periods as I continued presssing `l`.

Why am I getting this behavior and how could I achieve my expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASCII character `.` has the integer value 46. The `picture-self-insert` function passes its argument as a count, along with the value of the `last-command-event` variable, to the `picture-insert` function. For your case, this results in 46 insertions of the value of `last-command-event`, which happens to be whatever key you pressed.

In your `lambda` functions, replace `(picture-self-insert (string-to-char "."))` with:

```
(picture-insert ?. 1)
```

This will perform 1 insertion of the `.` character.

Comment: I noticed there was one unusual behavior. When I use `picture-insert` to insert a character when I'm at the beginning of a line, it jumps what seems to certain number of spaces forward. It varies every time. But seems to be 1 greater than the spaces inserted from previous time. But `picture-self-insert` inserts a character at the beginning of the line as we would expect. This might be out of the scope of my question, but do you have an idea of why this is? I removed all modes that seemed related to indentation and this still happens.

Comment: This is because before it calls `picture-insert`, `picture-self-insert` calls `picture-update-desired-column`. You might try calling it the same way prior to your `picture-insert` call: `(picture-update-desired-column (not (eq this-command last-command)))`.